# The messaging entity could not be found exception is thrown when publishing message from saga in MassTransit

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

When raising messages within a saga with the MassTransit transport set to Azure Service Bus the following exception is raised and an error is placed on the error queue:

> Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description:
> The messaging entity 'sb://xxxx-prod-bus.servicebus.windows.net/Api/StateMachine-MessageEvent' could not be found.

However, if the saga runs again, the message is successfully published. After looking at the Topic that the message is trying to be published to, the Topic for the first time does not exist but seems to get created afterward, however, the `Auto Delete On Idle` property on the Topic is set to 5 minutes so after a period of inactivity the Topic disappears and the error reappears.

[image]

The message contracts are declared exactly the same as the MassTransit documentation (https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/automatonymous.html#publish) using an interface and a type to wrap up the saga instance state:

```
public interface ExampleMessage
{
    Guid OrderId { get; }    
}

private class ExampleMessageEvent :
    ExampleMessage
{
    public ExampleMessageEvent(Instance instance)
    {
        SomeProp = instance.SomeProp;
    }

    public string SomeProp { get; }    
}
```

Other handlers are only subscribing to the interface of `ExampleMessage`, so I'd expect the publish to just continue even if nothing was listening on the concrete type topic?

What is the best way to avoid these issues? I've tried using retries to see if it recreates the exchange however nothing is created on the re-try.

It seems that the default for the temp topic gets the 5 minutes from [here](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/449ebad312acefc08724f57b18a17c2d8bb53ce8/src/MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport/Configuration/Defaults.cs#L78)
. However, I'd expect that if the topic doesn't exist when publishing the message it would just get created again?

The full exception message that was raised is:

> Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description: The messaging entity 'sb://something-prod-bus.servicebus.windows.net/Something.Api/SomethingStateMachine-SomethingRequiredEvent' could not be found. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions.  TrackingId:2f9c9776-08d5-41ab-81ba-3ec9011c2a90_G49, SystemTracker:something-prod-bus.servicebus.windows.Something.Api/SomethingStateMachine-SomethingRequiredEvent, Timestamp:2019-12-13T23:13:46.

And full stack trace:

> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessagingEntityNotFoundException:
>
> at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender+d__58.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy+d__19.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy+d__19.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender+d__45.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Transport.ServiceBusSendTransport+SendClientPipe`1+<Send>d__5.MoveNext (MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core, Version=5.5.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa)   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)   at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Transport.ServiceBusSendTransport+SendClientPipe`1+d__5.MoveNext (MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core, Version=5.5.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa)
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1+<GreenPipes-IPipeContextSource<TContext>-Send>d__8.MoveNext (GreenPipes, Version=2.1.4.118, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b800c4cfcdeea87b) at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1+<GreenPipes-IPipeContextSource-Send>d__8.MoveNext (GreenPipes, Version=2.1.4.118, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b800c4cfcdeea87b)
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1+<GreenPipes-IPipeContextSource<TContext>-Send>d__8.MoveNext (GreenPipes, Version=2.1.4.118, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b800c4cfcdeea87b) at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at MassTransit.Transports.PublishEndpoint+<Publish>d__17`1.MoveNext (MassTransit, Version=5.5.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa)
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at MassTransit.Transports.PublishEndpoint+d__17`1.MoveNext (MassTransit, Version=5.5.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa) at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at MassTransit.Context.InMemoryOutboxConsumeContext+<ExecutePendingActions>d__10.MoveNext (MassTransit, Version=5.5.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa) at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.InMemoryOutboxFilter`1+d__1.MoveNext (MassTransit, Version=5.5.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa)
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.InMemoryOutboxFilter`1+<Send>d__1.MoveNext (MassTransit, Version=5.5.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa) at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at MassTransit.ApplicationInsights.Pipeline.ApplicationInsightsConsumeFilter`1+d__14.MoveNext (MassTransit.ApplicationInsights, Version=5.5.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa)

Comment: Do you have an example exception? I'm wondering if there is an ordering/dependency issue with topic creation that I need to fix.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I've just added the full exception message and stack trace to the question.

Comment: Ah, I think it's the period of inactivity. I should change the send endpoint code so that if it's sending to a temporary entity, and the elapsed time is close to that lifespan, it resets and will recreate that entity again to ensure it's present after the elapsed time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a class that implements the published interface, you need to publish as the actual message interface. I'm guessing the one thing that your example above left out is the fact that `ExampleMessageEvent` class is actually private (or internal).

When you publish in the saga, cast the class to the interface type so that it doesn't create a temporary topic for the class.

```
.Publish(context => (ExampleMessage)new ExampleMessageEvent(...));
```

Comment: That's correct my actual implementation of the message is private, does that effect how the topic is created? I actually ended up with a cast like your example and that works perfectly fine. Thanks 

Comment: Yes, internal/private types are setup as auto-delete (or temporary) since they aren't visible outside the publisher.